# How to connect an image to a specific email

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcedx, images

I have a folder with 10k images - a specific image to each user I have in my system.
I want to send an email and present to each user the image that belongs to him.
Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) Upload all the images into Marketing Cloud. You can give a user friendly name 
 to the external keys of your images.

2) Create a sendable Data Extension with an ID field where you need to put the external key of the image and you can have other fields such as FirstName, LastName, email, etc.

3) In your email, use this piece of code in a Free Form block:

```
%%[ 
Var @link, @email
Set @email = emailaddr
Set @link = Lookup('DE_Name','ID','email',@email) 

]%%

%%=ContentImagebyKey(@link,"default_image_link_external_key_here")=%%
```

4) Send this email to your sendable DE.